# std::thread communication issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am building a multithreaded application, but I've got a problem.
In the application I'm using a variable to communicate between the threads but it does not work. So when you type in *exit* the application does not stop executing.

**The code:**

```
//Program that controls an cadrocopter with the use of a
//Raspberry Pi, MPU 6050, an ultrasonic sensor, an HMC5883L and Arduino Leonardo
//to compile use "g++ ./quad.cpp -o ./quad -std=c++0x -pthread"
//
//Copyright Jan Hendrik Farr

#include <iostream>             //used to input data
#include <string>               //used to procces the userdata
#include <stdlib.h>             //used to convert strings into floats
#include "./serial/serial.h"    //used to communicate with the Arduino
#include <thread>               //used to do multithreating

using namespace std;

//userinterface thread
void userInterface(int cmdPos1, float cmdPos[]){
    string cmd = "";

    cout << "************************" << endl;
    cout << "* Quadrocopter control *" << endl;
    cout << "*       software       *" << endl;
    cout << "*                      *" << endl;
    cout << "*     version 0.1      *" << endl;
    cout << "*                      *" << endl;
    cout << "* Copyright J.H. Farr  *" << endl;
    cout << "************************" << endl << endl << endl;

    while(cmdPos1 != 4){
        cin >> cmd;

        if(cmd == "move"){
            cin >> cmdPos[0] >> cmdPos[1] >> cmdPos[2] >> cmdPos[3];
            cmdPos1 = 1;
            cout << endl << endl;
        } else if(cmd == "move+"){
            cin >> cmdPos[0] >> cmdPos[1] >> cmdPos[2] >> cmdPos[3];
            cmdPos1 = 2;
            cout << endl << endl;
        } else if(cmd == "land"){
            cmdPos1 = 3;
            cout << endl << endl;
        } else if(cmd == "exit"){
            cmdPos1 = 4;
            cout << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "invalid argument!!" << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

//algorithm
void algorithm(float tele[], int cmdPos1, float cmdPos[]){
    while(cmdPos1 != 4){
        switch (cmdPos1){
            case 2:
            cout << "works!!";
            break;

            case 1:

            break;

            case 3:

            break;
        }
    }
}

//gets telemetrydata from mpu
void gettelempu(float tele[], int cmdPos1){
    while(cmdPos1 != 4){

    }
}

//gets height from ultrasonic sensor
void getheight(float tele[], int cmdPos1){
    while(cmdPos1 != 4){

    }
}

//main function
int main(){
    //telemetry data
    float tele[12] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    //what to do
    int cmdPos1 = 0;
    //where to go
    float cmdPos[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    thread t1(userInterface, cmdPos1, cmdPos);
    thread t2(algorithm, tele, cmdPos1, cmdPos);
    thread t3(gettelempu, tele, cmdPos1);
    thread t4(getheight, tele, cmdPos1);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better not use the `using namespace std`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: When an integer is given as a function argument by value, a copy if taken. Assigning to "cmdPos1" in one of your threads will only change that local copy, and the other threads cannot see it. You need to use a flag variable which is shared, or even better, used a library with a higher level abstraction than raw threads (which should be rarely needed these days).

Comment: Or you can pass `cmdPos1` by reference to your threads with `std::ref`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void gettelempu(float tele[], int cmdPos1)
```

This function gets its own copy of `cmdPos`; at the time when it's called, the value passed to it is `0`, and the function never changes that value, so the loop never terminates. Same thing in `algorithm` and `getheight`.

In order to change the value of this argument in one place and have other functions see that change the functions have to take the value by reference:

```
void gettelempu(float tele[], int& cmdPos1)
```

and when the thread is created you have to pass a reference:

```
thread t3(gettelempu, tele, std::ref(cmdPos1));
```

But wait, there's more! There's no guarantee that changes to `cmdPos1` that are made in one thread will be visible to other threads. To ensure this, make it atomic. In `main`, change

```
int cmdPos1 = 0;
```

to

```
std::atomic<int> cmdPos1 = 0;
```

and change the function signatures to take an `std::atomic<int>` instead of an `int`:

```
void gettelempu(float tele[], std::atomic<int>& cmdPos1)
```